# Unable to import CSV with decimal degrees lat/long data into Google Earth

Tags: google-earth

Degrees Minutes Seconds works:

```
code,latitude,longitude,feature1
point1,45 12 5.3634,25 38 6.6444,3
```

Decimal Degrees doesn't work:

```
code,latitude,longitude,feature1
point1,45.2014897,25.6351792,3
```

Any chance of being able to use decimal degrees without having to convert all my data?

Running Google Earth Pro `7.3.3.7786 (64-bit)` on Linux.

[image: Image of error received]

Comment: Decimal Degrees should work fine, it's the format used natively in Google Earth and in KML.  I saved your "Decimal Degrees" example as a CSV, and it imported just fine into Google Earth Pro (ver 7.3.3.7786, 64bit on Windows 10). Can you tell us more about what isn't working, or what errors you're seeing?   Could it be that some other row of your full CSV contains invalid data?

Comment: @ChristiaanAdams I get the "Found zero features in file: /projects/test.csv" error. I'm able to select the lat/long fields in the import wizard, but after I click finish, I get that error. I'm only using that one single line in the CSV just for testing, so no other lines can be the cause. The only difference between my test and yours is that I'm running Linux. Could it be that it has something to do with the region/localization settings as well?

Comment: I managed to work around this issue by converting everything to KML format using this as a reference: https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/csvtokml?csw=1

Comment: Great, glad you got it to work.  Hmm... yeah, it might be a difference/bug in the Linux version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import csv file, Google Earth asks you about the columns of the coordinates. Then it asks you about the format of all the columns/fields of your csv file. For your coordinates select text format. This is the solution.

Comment: Indeed, by setting the fields as text I was able to import the CSV file. Thanks for that. No need to convert to KML anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

I followed all these solutions and none worked.
Then I remember that google intelligently asks about the coordinate´s format: Integer, String, or FLOATING POINT.
My coordinates had points and were actually real numbers, so selecting floating point fixed everything. Example of my lat and long: -23.8069034 -70.3945338 
NOTE that it does NOT matter if the rest of the fields are in integer or string format, Google Earth does not care about those, it only cares about the LAT and LONG data format (select FLOATING POINT for them).
My csv files were created with excel.